# I'm trying to replace/convert all the A's and B's in a particular column to 1 and O in a csv file

Tags: python, replace, drop

This is the error i'm getting

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [141], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 repl = {'Y':'1', 'N':'0'}
----> 2 prices_dataframe['col_state'] = prices_dataframe['col_state'].replace(repl, regex=True)

TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable
```

This is what i have tried

repl = {'Y':'1', 'N':'0'}
prices_dataframe['col_state'] = prices_dataframe['col_state'].replace(repl, regex=True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `replace()` method is unique to strings, and at some point the value you are trying to replace is being a boolean (True or False). If you still want to replace it, you can transform the value into a string:

```py
prices_dataframe['col_state'] = str(prices_dataframe['col_state']).replace(repl, regex=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however i'm still getting the same error. I tried a simpler code               prices_dataframe = prices_dataframe.replace('Y','1').                                                        TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [148], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 prices_dataframe['col_state'] = str(prices_dataframe['col_state']).replace(repl, regex=True)

TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable.                   and this is the response i'm getting.

Comment: @Dera Can you post the code snippet that is having this error? Looking better, apparently the `prices_dataframe` variable is being a boolean.

Comment: Hi Joan, thanks for your replies. Have been able to fix the error. Apparently, i needed to start running the code from the begining instead of just running that line of code alone